# make shiny dateInput return NULL or empty character

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a shiny app that allows the user to save value from the `input` slots into a SQL Server Database.  One of the things I would like to have an option to do is delete a currently existing date.  To do that, I need a way to pass either `NULL`, `NA`, `""` or *something* that I can use to set the value in the database to NULL.

`dateInput` isn't cooperating with me, however, and I can't figure out how to make the date input type return anything other than a date (which makes but happens to be inconvenient at this moment).

Can anyone think of a way to get a date input field that will pass either a date or `NULL` (or some equivalent)?

(In the example here, I would want the text below the input field to appear as `NULL`, `""`, etc. instead of an integer)

```
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    wellPanel(dateInput(inputId = "date",
                        label = "Choose a Date"),
              verbatimTextOutput("selected"))
  ),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output){
    output$selected <- 
      renderText({
        input$date
      })
  })
)
```

Comment: "One of the things I would like to have an option to do is delete a currently existing date." By this, you mean "currently existing date in the SQL server database" ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I can easily write the SQL query do set the date to NULL in the database, but can't figure out how to get a value from `dateInput` that will trigger the query.  (The issue being that if you leave the date input blank, it defaults to the current date)

Comment: Yes, `dateInput` returns the present date in the user's timezone if the `value` parameter is not specified. To get around the situation, can you check `date` value being returned from `dateInput` against your database values(date) each time and if you find it's repetitive, you can send NULL to database.

Comment: I don't think that will work in the long run.  If the database value is 2015-12-01 and the user wants to delete it today, deleting the contents of the input field would make it look like the value was being set to NULL when in fact it is being replaced with today's date.